# Randomizing Dijkstra algorithm input

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra

I've been studying the Dijkstra algorithm for a while now and i'm trying to randomize it's inputs to get some data about it's runtime. The thing that is bothering me is when the input is created (randomized using rand() and srand() on C++) there is a chance that many of the edges created will be the same, thus creating a smaller graph than i previously stated and wanted, making my results less reliable in a way. I've been trying this for the past 2 days and so far have made zero progress towards a solution, or at least one that won't mess with the O(mlogn) complexity of the algorithm.

I have created a minimum spanning tree already but creating the remaining edges without passing through the same one twice is what i'm not being able to do.

I've been using an implementation i found on a quora post by Avinash Kumar:

```
// Time complexity : O(ElogV)
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
typedef vector< pii > vii;
#define INF 0x3f3f3f3f
vii *G;   // Graph
vi Dist;  // for storing the distance of every other node from source.
/*==========================================*/
void Dijkstra(int source, int N) {
    priority_queue<pii> Q;
    Dist.assign(N,INF);
    Dist[source] = 0;
    Q.push({0,source});
    while(!Q.empty()){
        int u = Q.top().second;
        Q.pop();
        for(auto &c : G[u]){
            int v = c.first;
            int w = c.second;
            if(Dist[v] > Dist[u]+w){
                Dist[v] = Dist[u]+w;
                Q.push({Dist[v],v});
            }
        }
    }
}
/*===========================================*/
int main() {
    int N, M, u, v, w, source;  // N-total no of nodes, M-no. of edges, 
    cin >> N >> M;              // u,v and w are the end vertices and the weight associated with an edge
    G = new vii[N+1];

    for(int i=0;i<M;++i){
        cin >> u >> v >> w;
        G[u].push_back({v,w});
        G[v].push_back({u,w});
    }
    cin >> source;
    Dijkstra(source,N);

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<Dist[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After calling `rand()`, why don't you first check if the generated edge is already in the graph or not?

Comment: This is not Dijkstra's algorithm, looks more like Yen's variant of Bellman-Ford.

Comment: 1- won't checking if the edge is already on the graph make it really unefficient? The graphs are a bit large (around 15000 edges) and even if i check, i don't think that will remove the chance of that edge not appearing again and again, making the runtime a disaster.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2- I corrected it, that is the one i'm using, i copied it wrong.